# What is the difference between scanf("%[^\n]*c", sen); and scanf(" %[^\n]*c", sen); 2nd one is giving correct result

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char ch, s[100], sen[100];
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    scanf("%s", s);
    scanf("%[^\n]*c", sen);
    printf("%c\n%s\n%s", ch, s, sen);
    return 0;
}
```

On executing there is space before `sen` is printed. While when putting space before `%[^\n]*c` in `scanf`, there is no space there as required. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The `"%[..]"` conversion specifier does NOT discard leading whitespace (e.g. `' '` space, `'\t'` tab, `'\n'` newline (and others)). So you must manually insert a `' '` space before it if you need to consume leading whitespace. (`"%c"` and `"%n"` likewise do not consume leading whitespace, .. all other conversion specifiers do)

So for instance if the prior conversion with `"%s"` leaves the `'\n'` character in `stdin` unread (it does), then using `scanf("%[^\n]*c", sen);` will fail to read anything as it will see the `'\n'` left by `"%s"`. Adding the space before it causes the `'\n'` to be discarded, so you will read up to the next `'\n'` into `sen`. See [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: Note that the `*c` at the end of the format string is useless, and either should be removed (my preference), or changed to `%*c` (what the OP probably intended).

Comment: Good catch,  I read right over that as `%*c` I've seen it so many times... `:)`

Comment: So what is happening in this? Why is it not showing correct result?   @DavidC.Rankin                                                                                
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        int main() 
        {
        char ch, s[100], sen[100];
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        scanf("%[^\n]*c", s);
        scanf("%[^\n]*c", sen);
        printf("%c\n%s\n%s", ch, s, sen);
        return 0;
       }

Comment: @RaghavSharma when you call `canf("%c", &ch);`, a single character is read from `stdin` all others remain. When you call `scanf("%s", s);` all character up to the next whitespace following a non-whitespace character are read leaving the whitespace (a `'\n'` if there was only one word on the line). When you call `scanf("%[^\n]*c", sen);` the `'\n'` character is the first character waiting in `stdin`, so the call reads nothing stopping at the first `'\n'` (which just happens to be the very first character -- so nothing is read). When you add a `' ' ` before it, the `'\n'` is discarded.